# How to exit a single turn of a `for` loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

In a loop like so,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int i_foo;

    i_foo = foo();
    if (i < 5)
        return; //<-------- Right here

    footwo();
}
```

How would I return that one particular turn of the loop?

I know that I could make footwo() execute under the condition that `i >= 5`, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make the loop exit (just the once).

For more explanation, I would like the for loop to start back at the beginning and add 1 to `i`, as if it had just finished that particular "loop" of the loop.

(I could not find an answer to this based on the strange wording, but if there is one just direct me and I will happily take this down.)

Comment: Document yourself on `break` and `continue`.

Comment: `footwo()` will never execute as your for loop will exit when `i == 5`.

Comment: Continue was what I was looking for, thank you. And I meant to have `ifoo = foo()`, see edit

Comment: As close as I can understand you, you want `continue`.  That basically takes you to the bottom of the loop and then the `for` test is re-executed for the next iteration.  `break`, on the other hand, would take you to just after the bottom `}` of the loop.  (But even the most simplistic C tutorial would cover this, so you *really* need to get some good background education before going much further.)

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks, but I have enough background information. I must've skipped over the page in my first C++ book that taught the `continue` syntax of loops a year ago when I read it.

Comment: Then get yourself a good reference book so you can jog your memory when you're trying to do something a hair "different".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (i < 5)
    continue;
```

This jumps straight to the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean but if you're checking the condition of `if (i < 5)` then just use the keyword `continue`.  If the expression is true the loop will `continue`.

Comment: No prob Jim, hope you enjoy the coding.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly what you're saying, but to clear up a bit of terminology, I think you mean to say "iteration" when you're saying a "turn of the loop" or a "loop of the loop." Common terms allow for better clarity.

As to your issue:

If you use the `continue` keyword, it allows you to skip to the next iteration. If you use the `break` keyword, it will skip past the entire iteration structure (out of the for loop entirely). This also works with `while` statements.

Comment: Also, to clear it up a little further, `continue`, `while`, etc are commonly known as "control structures".

Comment: Thank you, I originally had iteration but changed it in case the term actually meant the whole of the loop (I wasn't sure at the time, didn't want confusion).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `continue` to terminate the current iteration of a loop without terminating the loop itself. But depending on how your code is structured, an `if` statement might be cleaner.

Given your example, you might want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int i_foo;

    i_foo = foo();
    if (i_foo >= 5) {
        footwo();
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you meant to assign the result of `foo()` to `i_foo`, not to `i`.

A `continue` can be simpler if you need to bail out from the middle of some nested structure, or if you need to bail out very early in the body of the loop and there's a lot of code that would be shoved into the `if`.

But in the case of nested control structures, you need to remember that `continue` applies only to the innermost enclosing loop; there's no construct (other than `goto`) for bailing out of multiple nested loops.  And `break` applies to the innermost enclosing loop *or `switch` statement*.